# Cloudera Mesos - When mesos-slave is stopped, current job get in 'LOST' status

Tags: cloudera, mesos

Cloudera Mesos - When mesos-slave is stopped it stops any further job processing. However, if a job is currently in progress, it gets in 'LOST' status. How to prevent it? Also, how can i inform mesos to complete the current job and then shutdown the mesos-slave?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Maintenace operator API in Mesos where you can ask Mesos to drain node (finish all tasks) and then turn it off but this feature must be enabled in a framework you are using.

http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/maintenance/

Comment: Hi, yes this article does makes sense.